# Why has my xkb/symbols/pc modification been only half successful?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

I am attempting to remap my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to either of the two <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys. After messing around with `xmodmap` for a few hours, I stumbled on a question here which indicated that a better way to make permanent changes to keymaps is by modifying the files in `/usr/share/X11/xkv/symbols`.

I changed the line in the file pc pertaining to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to read:

```
key <CAPS> { [ Control_L ] } ;
```

However, all this did was remove <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> (capitalisation) functionality. I amended the line to the following:

```
key <CAPS> { [ Control_L, Control_R ] } ;
```

Which made no difference.

I have looked in `/var/lib/xkb`, and found only `README.compiled`, even after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, so I don't know what I ought to have been able to delete.

Additionally, I have no idea where the manual for this system might be located, as I can't call

```
man xkb
```

Comment: I found exactly the same as you. When only changing to `key <CAPS> { [ Control_L ] }`; <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> has no effect any longer

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to edit package owned files such as `xkb/symbols/pc`, and in this case it's probably not needed.

I think that the `ctrl:swapcaps` option may be what you are looking for. The applicable man page is `man xkeyboard-config`.

To test in you current session if that does what you want, run this command:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps
```

To change it persistently, open the `/etc/default/keyboard` file for editing and change the line

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps"
```

Comment: consider the `ctrl:nocaps` option as well.   `ctrl:swapcaps` will put CapsLock on the Left Ctrl key while putting Left Ctrl on the CapsLock key (swapping them, as the name suggests).  `ctrl:nocaps` only changes the function of the CapsLock key, for when you absolutely positively don't want a CapsLock function anywhere near your keyboard.